# Branching SQL query with union all - performance

Tags: oracle, performance, union-all

I have a view which returns a list of projects for customers and for vendors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW projects_list AS
SELECT pr.*, 
       c.customer_name as party_name, 
       null as vendor_id, 
       null as vendor_data
  FROM projects pr 
  JOIN customers c on (pr.customer_id = c.customer_id)
UNION ALL 
SELECT pr.*, 
       v.vendor_name as party_name, 
       v.vendor_id, 
       v.some_column as vendor_data
  FROM projects pr 
  JOIN projects_of_vendors pov on (pr.project_id = pov.project_id) 
  JOIN vendors v on (pov.vendor_id = v.vendor_id)
```

basicly, I use this view to fetch projects list for either a customer or vendor, never both at once.
So, the view is queried either as:

```
SELECT * FROM projects_list 
 WHERE customer_id = 'A_CUSTOMER' and vendor_id IS NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM projects_list 
 WHERE vendor_id = 'A_VENDOR';
```

So basicly I would like to execute either first part of the union if there is no vendor_id set, or second part - if there is vendor_id set.

The problem is that when I access the view as a customer, oracle is spending long time to check the "vendor branck" when it is unnecessary, and the query is slow.

I now I could split this view in two and choose different view each time. But in reality I have many views  relying on this one and I do not access this one directly. I would have to duplicate each of the "child" views and make many changes in the application code to make this change.

Is there any way to "hint" oracle to skip first or second branch of the union?

Comment: You may wish to consider explicitly naming your select columns. Once you've done that, try adding an extra constant column to each of your unions, i.e. 'V' and 'C', then explicitly select that - does that help?

Comment: It seems it does, thanks

Comment: I'll paste as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to consider explicitly naming your select columns. Once you've done that, try adding an extra constant column to each of your unions, i.e. 'V' and 'C', then explicitly select that - does that help?

i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW projects_list AS
SELECT pr.*, 'C' Type
       c.customer_name as party_name, 
       null as vendor_id, 
       null as vendor_data
  FROM projects pr 
  JOIN customers c on (pr.customer_id = c.customer_id)
UNION ALL 
SELECT pr.*, 'V'
       v.vendor_name as party_name, 
       v.vendor_id, 
       v.some_column as vendor_data
  FROM projects pr 
  JOIN projects_of_vendors pov on (pr.project_id = pov.project_id) 
  JOIN vendors v on (pov.vendor_id = v.vendor_id)
```

Then use

```
SELECT * FROM projects_list WHERE Type = 'V'...
```